# Android Layout Help: 2 textview vertical Inline next to 1 button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout, android-linearlayout

I try to do this layout but i got only echec until now: 
- 2 textview vertical Align sharing 50% width with 1 button.
- all must be vertical centered.

Here is the mockup showing what i want:

[Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMtey.png)

Here is  my actual code :

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/PanelName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Parking Name"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/PanelAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Parking Address blablabla Paris"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_go"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="GO !"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: please clear what you want ?

Comment: What i want is exactly on the mockup ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Remove Nested `Linear Layouts` it's bad for performance. I have made some changes in your `Layout`. Make your `AppCompatButton Layout` inside `Relative Layout` and make it's width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and also Remove First `Linear Layout` inside `Root Layout`.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_go"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PanelName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Parking Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PanelAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Parking Address blablabla Paris Parking Address blablabla Paris Parking Address blablabla Paris"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_go"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#000"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="GO !"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is Screen.**

[image]

Comment: Perferct. Didnt know nested Linear Layout was bad for performance. Thanks A lot for your fast answer !

Comment: @NablaIluigEd Cheers !! Glad to help you. Up-vote it also if you can !! thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView One" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView Two" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSomething"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```